# Upanishads books with word by word translation and contemplation

Tags: upanishads

I am a beginner and I haven't found any books which have complete translation and contemplation.

Comment: Gita press Gorakhpur has with Shankar Bhashya included

Comment: see if https://www.upanishads.iitk.ac.in/mundaka?language=dv&field_chap_value=1&field_sec_value=1&field_mantra_no_value=1&etgb=1&setgb=1 is useful..

Comment: Swami Gambhirananda has word for word translations. "Eight Upanishads" consisting of Volumes 1 and 2. He also has a separate word for word translation of the the Chandogya Upanishad. Swami Madhavananda has a word for word translation of the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad.

Answer (score 1):

Complete word by word translation of Upanishad is available on various sites.

[Chandogya Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english)

[Isha Upanishad](https://dokumen.tips/amp/documents/isha-upanishad-word-for-word-translation-with-transliteration-and-grammatical.html)

[Mandukya Upanishad](https://baixardoc.com/download/mandukya-upanishad-word-for-word-translation-with--5c75a1d718feb?hash=e9cfa526b61c13e7fd653ca6afd7655f)

[Mundaka Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-shankara-bhashya)

[Taitereya Upanishad](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://estudantedavedanta.net/Taittiriya%2520Upanishad%2520-%2520Swami%2520Sarvanand%2520%255BSanskrit-English%255D.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjCgrj6893rAhUBzDgGHZ5CBPoQFjAOegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw0TwBET9vzyP1hrbShGS83n)

[Aitereya Upanishad](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://estudantedavedanta.net/Taittiriya%2520Upanishad%2520-%2520Swami%2520Sarvanand%2520%255BSanskrit-English%255D.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjCgrj6893rAhUBzDgGHZ5CBPoQFjAOegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw0TwBET9vzyP1hrbShGS83n)

[Kena Upanishad](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.scribd.com/document/348467564/Kena-Upanishad-Word-for-Word-Translation-with-Grammatical-Notes&ved=2ahUKEwjgveqw9N3rAhUJ4zgGHRVNDKEQFjAIegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1SrAYqqyOlfmHYodXcTtfa)

Other main Upanishads are available [here.](https://www.upanishads.iitk.ac.in/mundaka?language=dv&field_chap_value=1&field_sec_value=1&field_mantra_no_value=1&etgb=1&setgb=1)